# Why can I pass a getter reference to stream().mapToInt(...)?

Tags: java, functional-programming, stream

In the stream, I use mapToInt, in which I must pass a reference to a method with type ToIntFunction

the signature is simple

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ToIntFunction<T> {
    int applyAsInt(T value);
}
```

This means that the method to which I can pass a reference to mapToInt must contain an input parameter.
However, I manage to pass a getter that takes no incoming parameters and returns an int

```
myList.stream().mapToInt(Transaction::getValue).average().getAsDouble();
```

Here is the getter

```
public int getValue() {
return value;
}
```

Why is it possible to pass a reference to a getter to where the ToIntFunction type is expected where the applyAsInt method has an input parameter

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko
  Thank you very much, it really looks like it. Very useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a method reference to an instance method, the receiver is treated as the first parameter.

So `Transaction::getValue` is converted to the equivalent of `(Transaction t) -> t.getValue()`.

Comment: Correctly I understand that a reference to a static method is a real reference to a method. And a reference to a class instance method is syntactic sugar?

Comment: No.  It's still a real reference to a method.